# Does CocoaTouch guarantee the order of touch events?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I suspect some touch events are sometimes firing out of order. For example I expect:

```
touchBegan, touchMoved, touchMoved, ...touchMoved, touchEnded
```

However I think I'm getting:

```
touchBegan, touchMoved, touchMoved, ...touchMoved, touchEnded, touchMoved
```

**Does CocoaTouch guarantee the order in which touch events are fired?**

Edit - the behavior I'm seeing is: something that happens in touchEnded seems to be occasionally "un-done" by something that happens in touchMoved. I know touchEnded is firing because certain other things are happening.

Say touchMoved colors a square red. And touchEnded colors the same square blue and updates the text in a label. Most of the time I see just a red square as I'm swiping and then a blue square + label update when I stop swiping. However occasionally I see a red square + label update when I finish swiping.

Comment: I would assume so. Are you sure you don't have more than 1 touch going on?

Comment: I'm definitely using a single finger for the swiping motion. And no other fingers are touching the screen.

Comment: How are you measuring?  with NSLog?  NSLog statements are _not_ guaranteed to show up in order.  Breakpoints should however...

Comment: I did try logging however my particular error seemed to go away when the log statements were in. See the edit for more info.

Comment: Sounds almost like you sometimes have `touchesMoved` events queued up when you finish your touch event. But rather than the system completeing its queue before processing `touchesEnded` it fires off `touchesEnded` immediately. Since you can't reproduce the problem when logging, the system is possible lagging back due to the `NSLog`s and keeping things firing in order.

Comment: CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() should help figure out what order the events are being called in.